# Previous and forward buttons navigation in Liferay

Tags: navigation, liferay, parent-child

I am trying to find a way to navigate back and forward in the children pages of a main page in Liferay. I wish to do this by two buttons, Previous and Next. Is there a portlet to help me do this or should i search in other places. If there is no out of the box way that liferay comes with it how could i implement such a functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no portlet available to do so. You can use the `com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalServiceUtil`
and fetch the layout by it. From the layout object you can fetch the child pages(layouts) and then you can call the next and previous layout on button click.

http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/Layout.html
http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/LayoutLocalServiceUtil.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I will look into creating a new portlet with such functionality.